# compilation problem: "Extended mathchar used as mathchar" with mathastext

Tags: xetex, errors

When compiling a file using XeLaTex in TeXShop on Mac OS X, the console persistently hangs after the detection of the XeTeX driver:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
./paper.tex:53: Extended mathchar used as mathchar (71311379).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.53 \begin{document}
```

It's possible to continue the compilation, but I'd like to understand what is going on. The problem seems to be related to the `mathastext` package, which I use to allow math and text formatting both to use the TeX Gyre Termes font; commenting out the `\usepackage` line for `mathastext` relieves the problem.

I've seen [discussions from 2006](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2006-September/024278.html) (long predating the existence of `mathastext`) saying that there is a bug in the XeTeX distro (v. 0.995 rev. D) and the only solution is to compile from source. ([Google search results here.](http://www.google.com/search?q=latex%20%22extended%20mathchar%22)) The version of XeTeX currently installed on Mac OS 10.6.7 by TeX Live is 0.9997.4, but the problem persists, and I wonder if there is any newer intelligence on how to repair it or what causes it. I am having trouble building XeTeX manually.

---

**Edit, 20110505**

Because the discussion below became quite involved, I am summarizing the two main conclusions:

- There turns to be a bug in `amsmath` that requires the option `noendash` to be passed to `mathastext`. An alternate fix is offered by Philipp.
- Discussion of how to get math formatting to apply to non-math text, without looking like math mode, was transfered to a different posting: [applying math formatting to a non-math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17364/3935).

your code loading mathspec which itself caused behind the scenes fontspec to be loaded with option no-math?

---

**Edit: minimal example, as requested by Philipp**

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}            % replaces amssymb; do not use unicode-math
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}  % propagates document text font to math mode
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

The expected number of collisions in a given unit is \[E(collisions)=k\times\left(1-\left(1-\left(1/n\right)\right)^{{\left(k-1\right)}}\right)\]

\end{document}
```

---

**Another edit**, 2011.05.04, replying to JFBU's comment about `[no-math]`.

*With* `no-math` being passed to `fontspec`:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
...
\setmainfont[Scale=1,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
...
\usepackage[italic,noendash]{mathastext} % set *after* setmainfont
...
\begin{document}
au\(_{\rm3yā}\)
\end{document}
```

I get [image: with no-math]. But *without* `no-math` being passed to `fontspec`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
...
\setmainfont[Scale=1,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
...
\usepackage[italic,noendash]{mathastext} % set *after* setmainfont
...
\begin{document}
au\(_{\rm3yā}\)
\end{document}
```

I get [image: without no-math]. I believe these are the same; I chose ā because the height of the macron is very distinctive in Termes.

---

**Edit, 2011.05.04b**: In response to another comment of @JFBU, appearance of `\centerline{0123456789}\centerline{$0123456789$}` with and without `no-math` passed to `fontspec`.

With `no-math`:
[image: with no-math 2]

W/o `no-math`: 
[image: without no-math 2]

I see no obvious difference.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal example?

Comment: hello, I was idling on this site when I saw your message pop up. `mathastext` has hardly been tested with unicode engines (I know from first-hand source that the author does not even have a working xe(la)tex on his system... and only did a bit of testing with LuaLaTeX). The source of your problem may indeed quite probably be with `mathastext`. Try loading it with the `basic` option to see if it helps.

Comment: @brannerchinese: (breaking news) the author of `mathastext` has informed me that at his office, they have TL2010 since a few days, and that for the first time he could try out XeLaTeX. He says that a minimal document works fine: ` \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Andale Mono}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\setmainfont{Arial Black}
\Mathastext[Arial]
\begin{document}
\MTversion{normal}
Hello $world$

\MTversion{Arial}
Hi $again$
\end{document}` so please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @Philipp: Minimal example included in edit.

Comment: @brannerchinese: as a side remark, when using `mathastext`, one should load it *after* the `setmainfont` command. To return to your problem, it goes away when `amsmath` is not loaded. This should help locate the source of the error in `mathastext`. Will transmit to its author.

Comment: @jfbu: Thanks for your help. I'll look forward to hearing back at some later time.

Comment: @brannerchinese: yes, but your `\rm` switches to the main document font (this is set-up to be so by mathastext; it would also be the case with fontspec alone *without* the no-math option). Try `\centerline{0123456789}\centerline{$0123456789$}` with and without the no-math option to fontspec and you will see the difference. If you don't pass the option no-math to fontspec the digits in math mode will be typeset in CMR, but if you pass the option no-math they will be typeset in TeX Gyre Termes.

Comment: Hm. I see your point, but with and without `no-math`, there is no apparent difference between the two strings you prescribed (and with `mathastext` still being introduced after `setmainfont`). Adding the character ā to both strings, it appears in the first string but not in the second; it is not being made. I'll edit the OP again to show what I am seeing (without character ā added to your strings).

Comment: Also, there is no apparent difference in the font of the subscript in `au\(_{3yā}\)` with `\rm` removed. Without `\rm`, the vowel ā does not appear, regardless of whether `no-math` is present or not. **Bottom line**: to apply math formatting to non-math characters, I apparently need both `textasmath` and `\rm`.

Comment: @JFBU: I think our digression deserves separate discussion; I've posted it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17364/3935. Thanks for your forebearance, and I look forward to continuing the discussion. Also, sorry for having forgotten to ping you on the two previous comments to your comments.

Comment: @brannerchinese: good idea to open up this topic as another question/answer. I just posted my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/applying-math-formatting-to-a-non-math-font/17374#17374

Comment: @brannerchinese: may I suggest that you edit your question to point out that what you described was related to your code loading `mathspec` which itself caused behind the scenes `fontspec` to be loaded *with option no-math*? this would provide more complete information to the casual browser.

Comment: @JFBU: Okay, I've placed a terse summary at the end of the initial statement of the problem.

Comment: Just to add that I ended up here with the same error message and it turns out that I had a clash between unicode fonts and the `commath` package. Clearly there are multiple culprits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a problem due it seems to an interaction between `amsmath` and `mathastext`. As a temporary fix, load `mathastext` with option `noendash`.

EDIT [2012/10/18]. Versions 1.15x of `mathastext` uploaded to CTAN late September have incorporated a work-around to this `amsmath`+Unicode fonts problem. So it is not necessary to use the `noendash` option anymore. END OF EDIT.

The following compiles on my system:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}       
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[italic,noendash]{mathastext} 

\begin{document}


The expected number of collisions in a given unit is \[E(collisions)=k\times\left(1-\left(1-\left(1/n\right)\right)^{{\left(k-1\right)}}\right)\]

\end{document}
```

I switched to Times New Roman, as the TeX Gyre fonts are not available on the system I am currently on. I will edit my answer once I understand better what's going on.

---

Ok, it seems that the problem is related to the presence of the following two lines in `amsmath.sty` (lines 745-747)

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
  \mathchardef\std@equal\mathcode`\=\relax
}
```

and to the fact that `mathastext` redefines the minus sign in math mode with the following instruction:

```
\XeTeXmathcode`\- ="2 \symmtoperatorfont "2013 \relax
```

Furthermore the file `amsopn.sty` (loaded by amsmath) makes a definition of `DeclareMathOperator` which seems to involve also a certain macro which will contain `\mathcode'\-` (read the ' as a backtick). It seems that once `mathastext` has done its job with the line above to use the en-dash as minus sign, any call to `\mathcode'\-` throws an error, as one sees by compiling just the following two lines

```
\XeTeXmathcode`\- ="2 "0 "2013 \relax
\mathchardef\coucou\mathcode`\- \relax
```

in a TeX source with no package at all. So this situation creates a general incompatibility between `mathastext` and `amsmath` (same for LuaTeX as engine !!), for which the only (due to the AtBeginDocument above) current work-around I see is the following:

1. load `mathastext` with option `noendash`
2. immediately after `\begin{document}` put the line written below
3. if you use LuaLaTeX rather than XeLaTeX put the second line.

Line for XeTeX:

```
\XeTeXmathcode`\- ="2 \symmtoperatorfont "2013 \relax  % xetex
```

Line for LuaLaTeX:

```
\luatexUmathcode`\-="2 \symmtoperatorfont "2013 \relax % lualatex
```

Hope it helps. The author of `mathastext` should put this stuff in an AtBeginDocument instruction, but only if it is guaranteed this will be processed by TeX after the amsmath stuff. The following works on my system:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}       
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[noendash]{mathastext} 

\begin{document}
    \XeTeXmathcode`\- ="2 \symmtoperatorfont "2013 \relax


The expected number of collisions in a given unit is \[E(collisions)=k\times\left(1-\left(1-\left(1/n\right)\right)^{{\left(k-1\right)}}\right)\]

a\textendash b 

$a-b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiles here with TeX Gyre Termes.

Comment: @brannerchinese: ok thanks for the info. I have now provided a more complete answer, hopefully it will work on your system.

Comment: as an aside, the doc of `mathastext` says to load `fontspec` with option `no-math`. In the small example above this does not seem to matter, but I don't know in general. Anyhow this is completely unrelated to the question addressed here.

Comment: in fact the reason for loading `fontspec` with option `no-math` when using `mathastext` is the following: without it the 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:,;,=,+,-,(,),[,],/,! and ? characters mysteriously escape the mathastextization. An alternative is to immediately follow `\usepackage{fontspec}` with: `\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_set_false:N \g_fontspec_math_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @jfbu: I see no difference with and without option `no-math` in my own code, but I'll leave it in anyway.

Comment: @brannerchinese: do you have `\usepackage{mathastext}` after `\setmainfont`? if it comes before, then the font used in math will be the default Computer Modern, also for the digits, and then there will indeed be no difference if option `no-math` was passed or no to `fontspec`. If `mathastext` is correctly loaded *after*  `\setmainfont`  and only then will the document font be used in math mode. Then you will notice a difference. (my current computer has only LuaTeX not XeTeX so I had to comment-out `mathspec` from your code which might influence, I don't know, the math fonts.)

Comment: Okay — I've edited the original post to show that there is no apparent difference, with and without `no-math`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a glitch in `amsmath` that prevents it from working whenever a Unicode math font is used. Here is a fix for XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_mathcode_minus_int
\int_new:N \l_mathcode_equal_int
\exp_args:Nx \AtBeginDocument {
  \exp_not:n {
    \int_set:Nn \l_mathcode_minus_int { \XeTeXmathcodenum `\- }
    \int_set:Nn \l_mathcode_equal_int { \XeTeXmathcodenum `\= }
  }
  \mathcode \int_eval:n { `\- } = \number \mathcode `\- \scan_stop:
  \mathcode \int_eval:n { `\= } = \number \mathcode `\= \scan_stop:
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\AtBeginDocument {
  \XeTeXmathcodenum `\- = \l_mathcode_minus_int
  \XeTeXmathcodenum `\= = \l_mathcode_equal_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

The expected number of collisions in a given unit is \[E(collisions)=k\times\left(1-\left(1-\left(1/n\right)\right)^{{\left(k-1\right)}}\right)\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Philipp: great! the author of `mathastext` will be relieved to see he is not 100% the culprit ;-) by the way in your code the `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}` should be *after* `\setromanfont` (check for the fonts included in the pdf and you will see that if you do not permute you get LatinModern in math mode rather than TeX Gyre Termes).

Comment: @Philipp: will this fix to `amsmath` be somehow incorporated transparently one day in the Unicode engines? are there other problems related with amsmath in this regard?

Comment: I don't know what the policy regarding such engine-specific fixes is, but I'll ask on the LaTeX mailing list. Yes, there are numerous problems caused by the switch to Unicode fonts, see for example the fixes incorporated in the [`unicode-math`](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/blob/master/unicode-math.dtx) and the [`lualatex-math`](https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math/blob/master/lualatex-math.dtx) packages.

Comment: Answer from Will: “Speaking for myself, I guess it largely depends. We've spoken here before about adding a switch to deactivate inputenc in XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX but no proposals ever got off the ground. As for amsmath, that's still maintained by the AMS, and I believe they're currently working on an update to that at the moment -- it would be best to contact them directly. (I'm not sure who the best contact there would be.)”

Comment: @jfbu: See [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/2509) for answers.

Comment: @Philipp: thanks, I read it. It is understandable that the people in charge of `amsmath` should move cautiously in upgrading their material, which has been stable for many years and, besides, is quasi-indispensable for serious mathematics typesetting (now in combination with  `mathtools` add-ons and fixes).