# applying math formatting to a non-math font

Tags: fonts, xetex, text-manipulation

This post summarizes a digression that began in comments to a [different post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17265/3935) with User [JFBU](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu).

The basic question here is what commands are needed to get the full character-set of a non-math font (in this case, TeX Gyre Termes) to be accessible in math mode, for the sake of the diverse formatting that is possible in math mode.

I would like to open this question to the TeX.SE community now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be more an answer to your answer than to your question! ;-) Indeed I just want to clarify this issue of `mathastext` vs `fontspec` with or without its option `no-math`. What you say in your answer is due to the use of `mathspec` in your code. Indeed, here is an extract from `mathspec.pdf`:

> Actually, mathspec ordinarily loads
>   fontspec with the no-math option. To
>   cancel this, explicitly use the math
>   option: e.g.
>   \usepackage[math]{mathspec}.

Package `mathspec` (for XeLaTeX) is specially designed to set up the math fonts (for the Latin letters, Digits, and Greek letters) and it provides commands for defining also the math alphabets. It automatically loads `fontspec` with option `no-math`. It can be used to set up the Greek letters, and then one can load `mathastext` to set up the Latin letters and Digits (as well as a few more punctuation characters from the Basic Latin set).

Package `mathastext` was designed for traditional TeX engines, but it is usable with Unicode engines; as clearly stated in its docs it only deals with the Basic Latin subset of the Unicode universe. Thanks to your question/answer, I realize that it is possible to use it together with `mathspec` (I initially thought they would work one against the other). For example one can use `mathspec` to set up the font for the Greek letters, and let `mathastext` do its modest job with the Basic Latin characters. Already with standard LaTeX and T1 encoding, `mathastext` does nothing special for letters with diacritics such as é or à directly input in the source in math mode (I believe the same applies to `mathspec`).

Here is now a small document allowing you to test `mathastext` under XeTeX (or LuaLaTeX) with various Unicode fonts of your choice, with or without `mathspec` (XeTeX only), and also, when not using `mathspec` with or without the option `no-math` to `fontspec`. As it stands, the source does not input `mathspec` and you will be able to see the importance of `no-math` option of `fontspec` when using `mathastext`. But to see the Greek letters, also when input directly in math mode as `$α$` for example, you will need to uncomment the `mathspec` loading (XeTeX only). Hope it helps!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % problem with `\- !!! (see below)

%% \usepackage{mathspec}
%% \setmathsfont(Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{Arial}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
% The no-math option should be used for not interfering with
% mathsastext. Important: mathspec loads by default fontspec with
% the no-math option.

%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % syntaxe pour luatex
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % syntaxe pour xetex

\usepackage[noendash]{mathastext} 
% noendash because of amsmath, see first line
% after \begin{document}

%%% mathastext allows to define multiple math versions,
%%% beyond the default "normal" one:

\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % or any other font
\Mathastext[times]            % no space in the math version name

\setmainfont{Impact}          % this is a very heavy upright
                              % font
\Mathastext[impact]           % available on the computer at
                              % my office

\setmainfont{Arial}           
\Mathastext[arial]       

\newcommand{\textandmathandgreek}{   
   \centerline{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\rlap{ (text)}}
   \centerline{$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$\rlap{ (math)}}

   \centerline{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\rlap{ (text)}}
   \centerline{$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$\rlap{ (math)}}

   \centerline{0123456789\rlap{ (text)}}
   \centerline{$\mathrm{0123456789}$\rlap{ (math with \texttt{\symbol{92}mathrm})}}
   \centerline{$0123456789$\rlap{ (math)}}

   \centerline{!\,?\,*\,,\,.\,:\,;\,+\,\textendash\,=\,(\,)\,[\,]\,/\,\#\,%
   \$\,\%\,\&\,<\,>\,|\,\{\,\}\,\symbol{92}\rlap{ (text)}}
   \centerline{$!\,?\,*\,,\,.\,:\,;\,+\,-\,=\,(\,)\,[\,]\,/\,\#\,%
   \$\,\%\,\&\,<\,>\,|\,\{\,\}\,\backslash$\rlap{ (math)}}

   \centerline{αβγΔΓΦ\rlap{ (text)}}
   \centerline{$αβγΔΓΦ$\rlap{ (math, direct input)}}
   \centerline{$\alpha\beta\gamma\Delta\Gamma\Phi$\rlap{
       (math, named letters)}}

   \medskip
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
% FIX FOR THE AMSMATH PROBLEM WITH MINUS SIGN
%\luatexUmathcode`\-="2 \symmtoperatorfont "2013 \relax
\XeTeXmathcode`\- ="2 \symmtoperatorfont "2013 \relax

\MTversion{normal}  % font at the time of loading mathastext
\centerline{Default Text Font}
\textandmathandgreek

\MTversion{times}
\centerline{Times New Roman}
\textandmathandgreek

\MTversion{impact}
\centerline{Impact}
\textandmathandgreek

\MTversion{arial}
\centerline{Arial}
\textandmathandgreek

The main job of mathastext is to allow to
type the characters from the Basic Latin set \emph{as is} in math mode,
and to have them without further ado be in the same font as
the document text (possibly in italic, with
\emph{italic} passed to the package, and when the font used
does exist in Italic Style). But for Unicode
characters not in the Basic Latin set (such as é, or æ or ŋ)
they should be input in math mode within a \verb|\mathrm| or
similar math alphabet commands $\zeta=\int
\frac{\mathrm{é}}{\mathbf{æ}}d\mathit{ŋ}$, or alternatively
within a \verb|\text| command (from package amsmath)
$\zeta=\int \frac{\text{é}}{\text{\bfseries
    æ}}d\text{\itshape ŋ}$ (this offers more possibilities
as the \verb|\math..| commands are not cumulative).

Mathastext has options related to Greek letters but only in
relation to fonts in \TeX\ format (fonts in LGR encoding, or
the Euler font, or the Symbol font). The Greek letters can
be set up arbitrarily by another package: with Xe\TeX{}
one can use the package \emph{mathspec} to specify the Greek
letters, this is compatible with loading also mathastext for
dealing with Latin letters and Digits (a job which can also
be done by mathspec). 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I chose the Impact font in the code sample above, because it is not available with an Italic Style. So if you try the above code adding the option `italic` to package `mathastext` you will see that it does work with Times New Roman, or any other font with an italic version, but not with Impact, or say, Arial Black. This is normal behavior of `mathastext` and would be the same with traditional TeX fonts (the absence of italic shape provoking probably a substitution warning in the LaTeX log file).

Comment: @brannerchinese: I edited my earlier answer, because I made therein a wrong assertion regarding `mathspec`. Thanks to your answer which made me finally realize that!

Comment: in fact `mathspec` automatically loads `fontspec` and pass options to it,  so in the code above, if one un-comments the `mathspec` line, one can comment-out the `fontspec` one.

Comment: in the code above it would be better for readability to use `\textbackslash` rather than `\symbol{92}`

Comment: @JFBU: All this is clear. However, to use Roman characters with diacritics (and other non-lower ASCII Roman characters) in math mode, it seems one does still need `\rm`, correct? Also, if one wants formulas to have italic Roman script, then `mathastext` needs option `italic`, but in that case when math formatting is applied to non-formulas within the same document, they will be italicized unless they are explicitly turned off, for example with `\rm`. Correct?

Comment: @brannerchinese: I think the answer is yes on both counts, but I am not sure I understand what you mean by *math formatting*. By the way `\rm` is frowned upon, although perhaps in math mode it is not that bad (as I never use it I forgot its defects), because the `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, etc... share the defects of `\rm` etc... of not cumulating effects. The `\text` macro of amsmath is better.

Comment: and with `\setmainfont{Times}
\usepackage[noendash,italic]{mathastext} 
\let\olditdefault\itdefault
\renewcommand{\itdefault}{\rmdefault}
\Mathastext[Upright]
\renewcommand{\itdefault}{\olditdefault}` in your preamble you can alternate in your document between upright Basic Latin letters in math mode and italic ones: after `\MTversion{Upright}` letters will be as if you had used `\rm` on them, and after `\MTversion{normal}` you return to the italic. This macro has to be called outside of math mode.

Comment: it seems `\rm ab` in math mode is about exactly like `\mathrm{ab}` so I shouldn't have denigrated it; but this is only for short variable names, if one wants spaces one has to use `\textrm` which behaves better if `amsmath` is loaded (or only `amstext` which would avoid the Unicode difficulty we talked about elsewhere), and even has the shorter form `\text` (which takes the style of the surrounding text off math mode).

Comment: @jfbu: Thanks for your suggestions about `itdefault`. And you're quite right about `\rm`; I just use it for speed and readability.

Answer (score 1):

One answer, the one that [JFBU](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu) and I have been discussing in the comments to the other post, is to use package `mathastext` to accomplish this. `mathastext` is very good, but it does not appear to me that works exactly as described in the documentation.

I am using XeLaTeX and `fontspec` in order to get full CJK functionality (not illustrated here). P. 8 of the [`mathastext` documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) says

> note to users of XeTeX/LuaLaTeX with `fontspec`: it has to be loaded with the option `no-math`, and before `mathastext`.

[JFBU](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu) has also shown that the option `noendash` must be passed to `mathastext` in order to avoid a small conflict that presently exists with `amsmath`. (There is a different solution to the same problem by User [Philipp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/345/philipp), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17265/compilation-problem-extended-mathchar-used-as-mathchar-with-mathastext/17280#17280).)

However, I do not see any obvious effects of the `no-math` option. Below is minimal code designed to show the difference in output when `no-math` is passed to `fontspec`. A string of numerals plus the non-math character ā is output three times: first as text, then formatted simply as math, and finally formatted as math but with `\textrm`.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}            % replaces amssymb; do not use unicode-math
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage[italic,noendash]{mathastext}  % propagates document text font to math mode

\begin{document}

\centerline{0123456789ā}\centerline{\(0123456789ā\)}\centerline{\(\textrm{0123456789ā}\)}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

With the option `no-math` passed to `fontspec`:

[image: with no-math 4]

Without the option `no-math` passed to `fontspec`:

[image: without no-math 4]

I see no difference between the two outputs. The presence or absence of `no-math` does not affect the appearance of the text, and the non-math character ā does not appear in math mode unless `\textrm` is used.

So it appears to me that `mathastext` alone is not sufficient to get all the characters in a non-math font to appear with math formatting. I'd be grateful to know if there is a simpler way to accomplish this task than with `mathastext` plus `\textrm` in each math environment.