# Can I use delimiter for brackets of a non-math font in math mode?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, math-fonts

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[,Scale=1,FakeStretch=1,FakeBold=0]{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\setmathfont[range={"0028, "0029},Scale=1,FakeStretch=1,FakeBold=0]{CenturymodernTT-Regular.otf}



\begin{document}

    Some random text
        \begin{align*}
            \log x\left(\pi(x)-\pi\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)
        \end{align*}

    1234567890

\end{document}
```

I have looked at questions that sound similar but aren't really e.g.

[applying math formatting to a non-math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/applying-math-formatting-to-a-non-math-font)

[Unicode math at TeX primitive level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308749/unicode-math-at-tex-primitive-level)

[image: Output]

Notice how delimiter does not work with parentheses. I think it's because the font does not have math script and does not have the corresponding scaled brackets defined in the font file itself. Is there a way to make use of the delimiter of the usual CM font for this parentheses?

I have tried some scaling mechanism but I did not like the output very much because of alignment issues. To clarify, I would like to use the parentheses like this:

[image: Desired output]

I was able to produce this by editing specific glyphs inside the font. First, I took the NewCM math font, replaced some glyphs with old looking ones. Then I replaced some brackets by some old glyphs and added transformations such as scaling, moving vertically, etc. Unfortunately, even though I edited brackets from v1 to v7 in the glyph table, it did not cover all possible cases which makes the output look like this:

[image: current output after modifying brackets]

See how some brackets work but some don't (probably the ones that require the most scaling).

Hopefully that gives a good idea of what I  want to achieve and what I have tried.

Comment: You're trying to use non-math fonts for math. It cannot work.

Comment: Also, I can't see how parentheses are different in Latin Modern Math (or CM, anyway) from NewCMMath ones.

Comment: Off topic:  If both `amsmath` and `amsthm` are requested, `amsmath` should come first.

Comment: I have voted your question positively. I like the fonts old style :-).

Comment: haha ya I like them a lot too. That's why I am so invested in using this parentheses in all cases. If you want, here are the modified fonts https://github.com/proafxin/elemannt

Comment: @Masum I am very curious for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you want.

To begin with, you cannot borrow the parentheses from a non-math font and hope they scale with `\left` and `\right`: in order to do this, the font *must* support the feature and have a MATH table.

Second problem: you say

> Is there a way to make use of the delimiter of the usual CM font for this parentheses?

Let's see a few examples.

#### With NewCMMath only

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\begin{document}

Some random text
\begin{equation*}
\log x\left(\pi(x)-\pi\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)
\end{equation*}

1234567890

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### With Latin Modern Math for the parentheses

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={"0028, "0029}]

\begin{document}

Some random text
\begin{equation*}
\log x\left(\pi(x)-\pi\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)
\end{equation*}

1234567890

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### With legacy Computer Modern for the parentheses

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMoperators}{OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr} {bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {CMoperators}{"28}{CMlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{CMoperators}{"29}{CMlargesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}

Some random text
\begin{equation*}
\log x\left(\pi(x)-\pi\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)
\end{equation*}

1234567890

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Conclusion

I see no difference at all in the three pictures.

Comment: I have updated the post to clarify the question and what I have tried a bit better. Please check. I suppose I tried to directly edit the math table using this font which does not fix the output everywhere. So I thought maybe I could make the `\left(\right)` command use the bracket from this font for scaling rather the usual CM one. Now I am starting to think I need to edit the math table with this font for the remaining brackets.