# punctuation marks have different fonts in and out of equations in xetex

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am using xelatex to create a document in Armenian. I have the line

`\setmainfont [Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchUppercase] {DejaVu Serif}`

in my tex file to change the font to DejaVu Serif for the text. However the equations are still in Computer Modern. As a result punctuation marks, such as "," are different in and out of equation. This looks a bit ugly, because commas are very different in DejaVu Serif and Computer Modern. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check out the `mathspec` package, which allows you to set the maths text fonts.

Comment: You could use [`mathastext`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17273/9092) or [`unicode-math`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38093/9092) for more comprehensive support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mathspec` package allows you to set maths text fonts.  Unfortunately this doesn't actually solve the punctuation problem.  Code to do that was posted here: [Punctuation marks in math mode in xetex/mathspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38711/2693)  Here's an example.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % must be loaded before mathspec

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont [Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchUppercase] {DejaVu Serif}
\setmathsfont(Latin,Digits){DejaVu Serif}


% The following code is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38711/2693
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`,}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`.}
\DeclareMathSymbol{<}{\mathrel}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`<}
\DeclareMathSymbol{>}{\mathrel}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`>}
\DeclareMathSymbol{/}{\mathord}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`/}
\XeTeXDeclareMathSymbol{^^^^2026}{\mathinner}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{"2026}[\mathellipsis]
\makeatother


\begin{document}
This, a sample sentence, is some regular text.

\[
g(n) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3}n & \text{if } n \equiv 0 \mod 3,\\
\frac{4}{3}n + \frac{1}{3} & \text{if } n \equiv 1 \mod 3,\\
\frac{4}{3}n - \frac{1}{3} & \text{if } n \equiv 2 \mod 3.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This isn't a solution. Compare the commas in *This, a sample sentence,* with the comma in *mod 3,*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Ironically, `mathspec` doesn't take care of punctuation symbols. For those I've used the answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38711/punctuation-marks-in-math-mode-in-xetex-mathspec

Comment: @rdhs Oops. Thanks. I've modified my answer now incorporating question Levon linked to in his comment so that the answer is complete.