# How to disable everything related with math?

Tags: xetex, amsmath, compiling, classicthesis

When using [`ArsClassica`](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica/ArsClassica.pdf) package with [`tcolorbox`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), there is an error related to `amsmath` even when no math is used:

```
Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \hat.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \check.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \tilde.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \acute.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \grave.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \dot.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \ddot.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \breve.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \bar.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine \Umathaccent \vec.


Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \mathring.

! Extended mathchar used as mathchar (4203026).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.893 \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
```

#### Minimal non-working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym} %1
\usepackage{arsclassica} %Comment this out to make it compilable
\savesymbol{dddot} %1
\savesymbol{ddddot} %1

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[noendash]{mathastext} %2

\title{Quả cầu}
\author{}
\restoresymbol{TXF}{dddot} %1
\restoresymbol{TXF}{ddddot} %1

\begin{document}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```

1. Fix for [`command already defined`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-alreadydef.html). Related with `amsmath`.
2. Fix for [`Extended mathchar used as mathchar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17265/50146). Also related with `amsmath`.

Is there a way to disable `amsmath`? The engine is XeLaTeX

Comment: Your write-up isn't very clear, I'm afraid. In particular, could you provide a bit more information about the "several errors related to math when compiling"? Does your text maybe contain the characters `_`, `^`, and `$`? Please advise.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I've updated the question

Comment: Thanks for providing some additional information. Your code doesn't seem to load the `amsmath` package, so it's not clear how or why the warning messages (not *error* messages) arise. Please make your code compilable, and do please indicate which TeX engine you employ.

Comment: Your code still isn’t compilable. For sure , it’s lacking `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` statements.

Comment: @Ooker Your code works for me with an updated Miktex version and using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Load amsmath before arsclassica (tcolorbox loads it but this is too late there)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Indeed, the OP should be using the `report` document class...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't get this error (with xelatex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the hint (I deleted that comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some observations:

- If there really is no math anywhere in your document, there's no point in loading the `mathastext` package. Likewise, I can't see the need for loading the `savesym` package and for excecuting the pairs of `\savesymbol` and `\restoresymbol` directives.
- Assuming your TeX distribution has been updated recently -- specifically, more recently than 2017/10/31 -- all you really need to do is be sure to load `tcolorbox` *before* `arsclassica`.

The MWE (minimum working example) would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{arsclassica} 
\title{Quả cầu}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```

---

If your TeX distribution has *not* been updated recently, you should also take the following observations on board:

- You should use the `report` class, not the `article` class, with the `arsclassica` package. Why? Because you need to use a document class that provides the commands `\chapter` and `\chaptermark`. (The most recent version of `arsclassica` no longer requires a document class that provides `\chapter` and `\chaptermark`; that's why it's OK to use the `article` document class in the MWE shown above.)
- Specify the option `flushmargin` when running `\documentclass`. That way, this option will automatically get passed to the `footmisc` package (which is loaded by the `arsclassica` package).
- Last but definitely not least, be sure to load the `fontspec` package, and do specify a main font (via `\setmainfont`) that provides all the glyphs that occur in your input file.

A revised MWE (minimum working example) for older TeX distributions would thus be as follows:

```
\documentclass[flushmargin]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{arsclassica} 
\usepackage{fontspec}     
\title{Quả cầu}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need to load fontspec. arsclassica will do it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - If I don't include the `\usepackage{fontspec}` directive in the MWE, the double-accented characters aren't displayed properly, i.e., the base characters are displayed without any accents. Moreover, the log file doesn't indicate that the `fontspec` package was loaded.

Comment: Hm. Together with the remark about chapter (that I can't reproduce either) I wonder if you have some different files. I checked with `--recorder`: My (xelatex)-compilation only uses files from a current texlive updated today.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - This morning, I was working on a PC and a MikTeX installation that hadn't been updated since Feb. 2017 (tsk, tsk); the version of the `arsclassica` package that I had access to is V4.0, 2012/02/21. Just now, I reran the MWE on my personal laptop (which runs MacTeX2017 and is fully up to date); its version of the `arsclassica` package is 2017/10/31. Conflict solved. I'll edit my answer to modify the statement about needing to use the `report` document class.